# Python implementation of Conway's chained arrow notation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, math-expression-eval

A year ago, I implemented an evaluation algorithm for [Conway's chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) in Python. I'd like to get a review on my code, especially about readability and if it is pythonic. I'd also like to know if there is a bug. I'm not too much concerned about performance since this notation runs faster into unsolvable memory problems than it runs into long loops. For example, `resolve('3->3->2->2')` would have to build a list with 7.6 trillion strings if it didn't raise a `MemoryError` manually before.

```
# coding: utf-8


MAX_BYTES = 1 << 30


def do_brackets_match(chain):

    open_brackets = 0
    for c in chain:
        if c == '(':
            open_brackets += 1
        if c == ')':
            open_brackets -= 1
        if open_brackets < 0:
            return False
    return open_brackets == 0


def split_by_inner_bracket(chain):

    start, part3 = chain.partition(')')[::2]
    start, middle = start.rpartition('(')[::2]
    return [start, middle, part3]


def is_arrow_chain(chain):

    return '->' in chain


def resolve_pure(chain):

    assert '(' not in chain and ')' not in chain

    # remove whitespace
    chain = chain.replace(' ', '')
    chain = chain.replace('\t', '')

    # get values
    str_values = chain.split('->')

    # handle short chains
    length = len(str_values)
    if length == 1:
        return str_values[0]
    b = int(str_values[-2])
    n = int(str_values[-1])
    if length == 2:
        if n.bit_length() > 1024 or b.bit_length() * 8 * n > MAX_BYTES:
            raise MemoryError
        return str(b ** n)

    if b > MAX_BYTES:
        raise MemoryError

    # remove everything after a 1
    for i, s in enumerate(str_values):
        if str_values[i] == '1':
            str_values = str_values[:i]
            break

    # construct the next iteration step
    leading_chain = '->'.join(str_values[:-2])
    resolved_chain = '->('.join([leading_chain] * b)
    resolved_chain += (')->' + str(n-1)) * (b-1)
    resolved_chain = resolved_chain.replace('->1)', ')')
    if resolved_chain.endswith('->1'):
        resolved_chain = resolved_chain[:-3]
    return resolved_chain


def resolve(chain, show_progress=False, depth=0):

    while is_arrow_chain(chain):
        if show_progress:
            print(' ' * depth + chain)
        if '(' in chain or ')' in chain:
            part = split_by_inner_bracket(chain)
            if is_arrow_chain(part[1]):
                part[1] = resolve(part[1], show_progress, depth+1)
            chain = ''.join(part)
        else:
            chain = resolve_pure(chain)
    return chain


def main():

    print(resolve('2->3->3', True))
    print('----------------')
    print(resolve('2->2->3->3', True))
    print('----------------')
    print(resolve('3->2->3', True))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Output:

```
2->3->3
2->(2->(2)->2)->2
2->(2->2->2)->2
 2->2->2
 2->(2)
 2->2
2->4->2
2->(2->(2->(2)))
2->(2->(2->2))
 2->2
2->(2->4)
 2->4
2->16
65536
----------------
2->2->3->3
2->2->(2->2->(2->2)->2)->2
 2->2
2->2->(2->2->4->2)->2
 2->2->4->2
 2->2->(2->2->(2->2->(2->2)))
  2->2
 2->2->(2->2->(2->2->4))
  2->2->4
  2->(2)->3
  2->2->3
  2->(2)->2
  2->2->2
  2->(2)
  2->2
 2->2->(2->2->4)
  2->2->4
  2->(2)->3
  2->2->3
  2->(2)->2
  2->2->2
  2->(2)
  2->2
 2->2->4
 2->(2)->3
 2->2->3
 2->(2)->2
 2->2->2
 2->(2)
 2->2
2->2->4->2
2->2->(2->2->(2->2->(2->2)))
 2->2
2->2->(2->2->(2->2->4))
 2->2->4
 2->(2)->3
 2->2->3
 2->(2)->2
 2->2->2
 2->(2)
 2->2
2->2->(2->2->4)
 2->2->4
 2->(2)->3
 2->2->3
 2->(2)->2
 2->2->2
 2->(2)
 2->2
2->2->4
2->(2)->3
2->2->3
2->(2)->2
2->2->2
2->(2)
2->2
4
----------------
3->2->3
3->(3)->2
3->3->2
3->(3->(3))
3->(3->3)
 3->3
3->27
7625597484987
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code again I was able to discover some issues.

> `def do_brackets_match(chain):`

Actually a nice function to check if the input is a valid chain notation ... I was really surprised when I didn't find any call to it. `resolve_pure()` doesn't accept chains with parenthesis, so `do_brackets_match()` would be used in `resolve()`

> `def split_by_inner_brackets(chain):`

It looks a bit ugly to slice the result of `str.partition()` in order to discard the separator. Today I would prefer `str.split()` with `maxsplit=1`.

> `def resolve_pure(chain)`

First of all, I consider renaming this function to `expand_chain` or similar. I would also rename the variable `resolved_chain` to `expanded_chain` in that case.
Secondly, this loop is a bit confusing:

```
for i, s in enumerate(str_values):
    if str_values[i] == '1':
```

I should definitly rewrite the second line to `if s == '1'`. I mean, that's the whole point of using `enumerate()`, isn't it?

As you might have noticed from the examples, a chain which starts with `'2->2->'` always results in `'4'`. I could handle that special case.

> `def resolve(chain, show_progress=False, depth=0):`

As mentioned before, this function should call `do_brackets_match()`, probably right at the start. If it fails, it should raise an exception or at least print a message and return `''`. When evaluating the inner bracket, it might be useful to call `eval` in order to evaluate common arithmetic expressions like `(2*5+3)`.

Neither `resolve_pure()` nor `resolve` check for negative values which should be avoided as they can cause an error